# Could a cell phone carrier sell this privacy plan?

Tags: united-states, criminal-law, privacy, data-protection

Suppose Verizon offered a "privacy plan" (e.g., for $50 extra per month) in which they intentionally delete any location/ping/connection/dialing history data from their servers/towers such that all records from more than an hour ago are permanently gone.

Effectively, it will seem like your phone was never switched on until an hour ago.  Of course, your phone itself will still have records, but you could delete those on your own.

This might mainly help criminals (since police search warrants of phone activity will not be as useful), but even upstanding people value privacy and it could therefore be very profitable.

Does offering such a plan violate any federal USA laws? or any state laws?